No such element or plugin 'tiovxdlcolorconvert'. Not able to install thus gstreamer plugin
i'm not able to install this plugin. please write commands for installing this plugins using gstreamer in ubuntu.
I tried gst bad plugins, but this tiovxcolorconverter not included on these bad plugins.
i tried this command :-
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

In "tiovxcolorconverter" , ti stands for Texas Instruments. So all these ti plugins are provided by them. and these plugins supported by some specific hardware systems like Beaglebone , etc.
So, you can't install it on your ubuntu or fedora system.
It is just like :- "ximagesink" plugin is used for linux systems and you can't use it for windows systems.
